# While loop never ends

Tags: bash, shell, loops, while-loop

I'm working with bash and I'm trying to do something like this:

```
A=1
while [ $A=1 ]; do
    read line
    echo $line | grep test >/dev/null   
    A=$?
    echo $A
done
```

This script never ends even when the grep finishes successfully and A is set to 0. What am I missing here? Below is a sample of the output.

```
$ ./test.sh
```

<kbd>asdf</kbd>

```
1
```

<kbd>test</kbd>

```
0
```

<kbd>hm...</kbd>

```
1
```

Comment: $A=1 does not set $A to be 1. The = here would act as a comparison operator, but it's the wrong type... in addition, the spacing is incorrect

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the correct comparison operator. Bash has different operators for integer and string comparison.

In addition, you need the correct spacing in the comparison expression.

You need

```
while [ $A -eq 1 ]; do
```

See [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) for more

Answer (score 5):

I find Bash's syntax pretty awful - have you tried something like:

while [ $A -eq 1 ] ... ?

It may be trying to re-assign 1 to $A or something strange like that.

Comment: or at least put whitespaces between operands and `=` operator.

Comment: The = sign is still a comparison in this instance... but it's a string comparison. The whitespace is the crucial aspect

Comment: @Dancrumb good to know guys (not that I do much bash programming!) thanks, Andy.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
while [ $A -eq 1 ]; do
```

Comment: The spacing is critical - as written in question with no spaces, the test operator is checking whether '0=1' is an empty string, and it is not so the test passes and the loop continues.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the answers have focused on the integer/string and spacing problem, which is fine, but your code looks so unidiomatic that IMO it should be completely re-factored. Let's say the idea is to process lines until one line matches the regex 'test':

```
while read line; do      
  if [[ "$line" =~ test ]] && break
  # do something with $line
done
```

Of course this can be simplified further if you take advantage of text processing tools like sed:

```
sed -e '/test/,$d'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this instead. No need to call external grep.

```
while true; do
    read line
    case "$line" in
      *test* ) break;;
    esac
done 
echo $line
```

Comment: Interesting. What does the single parenthesis do? And why two semicolons?

Comment: that's part of the case/esac construct. See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testbranch.html

Answer (score -1):

Have you not tried this

```
while [ $A == "1" ]
   ....
done
```

**Edit:** Whoops since ***Dan*** mentioned my error I graciously admit my mistake and have edited this accordingly - Thanks ***Dan*** for the heads up...

```
while [ $A -eq 1 ]
   ....
done
```

Sorry! :(
Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: That's the string comparison operator, not the integer comparison operator

Comment: @Dancrumb: the OP is reading a character input from the bash script...not really an integer....unless you care to explain? Thanks for your input! :)

Comment: sure. The script is putting the return code from a call to grep in $A, so the value is definitely numeric... either a zero or a 1

Comment: @Dancrumb: OMG! never saw that... yeah the $? is the error-level code...whoops my bad....meh! Thanks Dan.... :) Sorry!

Answer (score -1):

All of your answers are in the [Advanced Bash-Scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/). It is awesome.